# Allow changing the order in which accounts are displayed on the user profile

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

On everyone's user page, in the summary tab, there are sections.
One section is called accounts.
It displays the accounts from most rep at the top, to lease rep at the bottom.
What if I wanted it to display my accounts in a different order?
For example, what if I want to display the accounts with the most badges at the top?  Please let us choose what accounts to show.

Comment: I don't like this because most users including myself want to see which sites a user has most reputation on. So it would be off-putting to have to do more research to find this trivial information. If there was a sort option there like sort by most badges, most recent, etc, I have no problem with, but don't think a user should be able to custom sort this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this feature request [might take a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/158100) to get implemented. Until it is done you can leverage [The Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to some extent to get statistical data across all sites. I used your example for the sorting based on badges to demonstrate how that can be done.

The query [Order all my accounts based on number of badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/271284/order-all-my-accounts-based-on-number-of-badges?accountid=4550877) iterates over all databases while inserting the result of

```sql
select db_name()
     , b.Name
     , u.id
from badges b 
inner join users u on u.id = b.userid 
where u.accountid = 4550877
```

in a temporary table that we use to build the final result set.

The query requires an accountid which you find by visiting your network account on StackExchange.com and then take the id from the url. Yours is [4550877](https://stackexchange.com/users/4550877/bob-the-zealot), mine is [281857](https://stackexchange.com/users/281857/rene).

Here is the complete script with comments to explains how it works:

```sql
---- accountid: Account on stackexchnage.com! "In the url on stackexchange.com"

-- create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO

-- reverse dbname split on . 
-- in -> StackExchange.diy.meta -> meta.diy.stackexchange
-- this sp is recursive !
create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @pos integer
      declare @rec nvarchar(250)
      set @res = @dbname 
      set @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @dbname) -- find next . in dbname
      if (@pos > 0 ) 
      begin
         -- if we found one, get the part after the .
         set @rec = substring(@dbname, @pos+1, len(@dbname))
         -- let's see if the remainder has some . as well
         exec #siteurl @rec,  @rec output -- recursive call!
         -- reverse by putting our result first
         -- then add the first bit
         set @res = @rec 
                  + '.' 
                  + substring(@dbname, 0, @pos) 
      end
   end;
go

declare @accountid int = ##accountid:int##  -- 4550877

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max)   -- holds build up sql string

-- result table for badges per site and the userid on that site
create table #all_badges ( site nvarchar(250)
                         , Name nvarchar(50)
                         , userid int
                         );
                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +'; -- switch database
               declare @url nvarchar(250) -- will hold the dbname swapped
               -- swap the dbname
               exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
               -- store in temptable
               -- notice the joun with Users table to
               -- be able to get the accountid
               insert into #all_badges 
               select @url
                    , b.Name
                    , u.id
               from badges b 
               inner join users u on u.id = b.userid 
               where u.accountid = ' + cast(@accountid as nvarchar) + ';'
   exec (@sql) -- execute our dynamic sql statement
   -- get the next database 
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

-- project the result
-- first column uses a spcial format that gets rendered as a Link 
-- this how it would look like:
-- http://site.stackexchange.com/users/1?tab=badges|site
select 'http://' 
     + site 
     + '.com/'
     + 'users/'
     + cast(userid as nvarchar)
     + '?tab=badges'
     + '|'
     + replace(site,'.StackExchange','') 
     , count(*) as [count]  
from #all_badges
group by 'http://' 
     + site 
     + '.com/'
     + 'users/'
     + cast(userid as nvarchar)
     + '?tab=badges'
     + '|'
     + replace(site,'.StackExchange','') 
order by count(*) desc
     
drop table #all_badges
```

On posting the top 5 result of the sites with the most badges for your account are:

```
site          | count
---------------------
Ell           | 37
StackOverflow | 18
Gaming        |  9
Chinese       |  9
Meta.Ell      |  8
```

Remember that SEDE is only updated once a week (in the weekend).